# Node error when I deployed smart contract - Web3.js

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, web3js, ether

I get this error when I deployed smart contract to my private chain.

```
Error: Node error: {"code":-32000,"message":"unknown account"}
```

This is my web3.js code.

```
 const bytecode = "0x608060405234801561001057600080fd5b506040516020806101018339810180604052602081101561003057600080fd5b8101908080519060200190929190505050806000819055505060aa806100576000396000f3fe6080604052348015600f57600080fd5b506004361060325760003560e01c8063c412eaba146037578063ca6158cb146053575b600080fd5b603d606f565b6040518082815260200191505060405180910390f35b60596078565b6040518082815260200191505060405180910390f35b60008054905090565b6000548156fea165627a7a7230582042b7071573f040950b28decc097069f3f208055692800cf2260019f40904af610029"
    var itemContract = new this.props.web3.eth.Contract([{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"getItem","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"itemId","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"name":"id","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"constructor"}]);

itemContract.deploy({
  data: bytecode,
  arguments:[1]
})
.send({
  from: decryptEtherAccount.address,
  gas: 0,
  gasPrice: '0',
}).on('error', (error) => {
    console.log("Error: ", error);
}).on('transactionHash', (transactionHash) => {
    console.log("TxHash: ", transactionHash);
}).on('receipt', (receipt) => {
  console.log("Address: ", receipt.contractAddress)
}).then((newContractInstance) => {
    console.log(newContractInstance);   
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

Could you give me any advise why I am getting this error, please?

Comment: Either `ecryptEtherAccount.address` is an illegal address, or you haven't unlocked this account on the node that you're connected to.

Comment: @goodvibration I have made ether account from web3.eth.accounts.decrypt() function. I have tried unlock ether account, but it was not succeeded. Do you know any way to unlock account?

Comment: https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.1/web3-eth-personal.html#unlockaccount (this one is for web3 v1.2.1, so make sure to read the one corresponding to the web3 version that you're using).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I used private chain, so I could deploy it when I deploy from node address.

If you want to deploy from any other address, it is better to use `sendTransaction` to deploy contract.