# How can I unlock my account

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, ether

I cannot unlock my account.

I decrypted my account from encrypted accoun, and want to unlock it to deploy contract.

However, I am getting this error,

```
 Node error: {"code":-32000,"message":"could not decrypt key with given passphrase"
```

This is my web3 code.

```
const decryptEtherAccount = await web3.eth.accounts.decrypt(etherAccount,'test!')
web3.eth.defaultAccount = await decryptEtherAccount.address
const account = await web3.eth.getAccounts()
const address = await web3.eth.personal.unlockAccount(account[0], decryptEtherAccount.privateKey, 1000)
console.log(address)
```

Are there any problems of my code?

Also, could we unlock account, not node?

Comment: Have you tried what I suggested to you in a comment on [your previous question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/76299/16043)?

Comment: @goodvibration Yes!! This code is what I did based on documentation. However, I didn't make my account by this function `web3.eth.personal.newAccount(password, [callback])` , so I think I don't need to unlock account. Did I made mistake ?

Comment: Yes, you did...

Comment: @goodvibration Sorry, where is it ...?

Comment: It's in `I think I don't need to unlock account`.

Comment: BTW, aren't you finding it a little awkward that the title of your question says "How can I unlock my account", and then in your comment above you say "I think I don't need to unlock my account"???

Comment: @goodvibration I misunderstood `node` for `account` in your comment on my previous question.  Now, I have to find out why the address is illegal address. Thank you !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can unlock account only for the account that made from `web3.eth.personal.newAccount(password, [callback]`.

If your address is made by in any other way, you don't have to unlock it.

You need your privatekey.